# when I execute mvn package, spring-boot-configuration-processor.jar will not be packaged。

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

When I execute mvn package, it complete success. But the spring-boot-configuration-processor.jar will not be packaged. What is the cause of this? Can anyone help me? Git address [code address](https://github.com/hello-world-demos/mvn-pacakge)

Comment: As you want all the dependencies to be included the final artifact, so you try with other maven plugins to create the fat or uber jar. One such plugin is `maven-assembly-plugin`

Comment: @harry  Good Idea。The answer is [github] (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/e743d5fe66302feca910f81a7285ca0caf3e1b84)

Answer (score 0):

See fatjar or ubberjar packaging.

By default the jar package your code, not rhe dependencies. If tou want to include your dependencies it's a fat or ubber jar.
The .class of your dependencies will be packaged in a single jar. Rhen your jar become self executable.
You can exclude dependencis from the final jar using the 'provided' keyword when you define a depency in the pom.

Be carrefull with transitive dependecies. Maybe you use a different version of a lib that one of another of your dependecy use.

Answer (score 0):

[https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot[Gitter][1]](https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot%5BGitter%5D%5B1%5D)
Andy Wilkinson @wilkinsona solved my problem
16:27
It's an annotation processor so it's only used at compile time. Spring Boot's Maven plugin automatically filters it out of the jar that it builds: [spring-projects/spring-boot@e743d5f](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/e743d5fe66302feca910f81a7285ca0caf3e1b84)